# Full duplex online audio conferencing

Tags: iphone, audio, audio-streaming, duplex, conferencing

Is it possible to build an app which allows for full duplex audio conferencing? Is there one out there I haven't found yet?

I work in a theatre and our comm system is failing. Everyone has smartphones so it would be easy to utilize these as comm systems. We use a full-duplex system with a talk button.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need an app.  WebRTC will suffice.

There are some off-the-shelf libraries that wrap everything up for you very nicely:

- RTC.io - http://rtc.io/
- PeerJS  - http://peerjs.com/

Since you'll be using headsets, I recommend disabling echo cancellation as you won't need it and it only hurts sound quality.